# How do I append Protovis chart to a specific HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, protovis

I have a div tag with id "chart" but how do I get Protovis to render the chart inside that tag?

I tried the canvas method but it did not work.

```
var vis = new pv.Panel().canvas("chart").width(width).height(height)
```

I need to keep my JS code the greates the chart as part of the framework I'm working on and can't have scripttags inside the HTML body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definitely works for me in the latest version of Protovis (3.2):

```
<div id="#chart-div"></div>

var vis = new pv.Panel().canvas('chart-div')
```

Make sure its the **root panel** though.

http://groups.google.com/group/protovis/browse_thread/thread/1ff9530cee6133ff

Comment: it did for me too now, I must have failed to append the tag to the document or something, I got it working now... Thanks

Comment: I fuc*ing love you man <3 I wasted so much time to find the right spot to put my protovis code. Finally...